# vscode javascript reserved keywords syntax color

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I finish typing process.env or console.log the original color green pops up but then it changes back to blue. I am quite used to it being only green as an identifier that it is a reserved word.

How can I retain that color for these reserved words and not have it pop back to blue?

VSCode Version: 1.43.0

VSCode Theme: Dark+ (Default Dark)

Language Mode: Javascript(Babel)

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92900 and set `semantic highlighting` to false.

Comment: that solved it, thanks!